# How do I use 2 variable in foreach in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

One variable is used for searching and
Another variable is used to display name based on id from DB

```
public function recorddisplay(Request $request)
 {

    $search =$request['search'] ??"";
    if($search != "")
    {
        $covidrecord=Covidrecord::where('fullname','LIKE',"%$search%")
        ->orWhere('province','LIKE',"%$search%")
        ->orWhere('district','LIKE',"%$search%")
        ->orWhere('localgovernment','LIKE',"%$search%")->paginate(15);
    }
    else{
        $covidrecord= Covidrecord::paginate(15);
    }

    $data = compact('covidrecord','search');

     $dataCovid=DB::table('coviddeathrecord')
     ->join('district','coviddeathrecord.district','=','district.id')
     ->join('province','coviddeathrecord.province','=','province.id')
     ->join('localgovernment','coviddeathrecord.localgovernment','=','localgovernment.id')
     ->get(['coviddeathrecord.*','district.district','province.province','localgovernment.localgovernment']);

    return view('admin.dashboard.display', compact('dataCovid'))->with($data);

}
```

This is the blade

```
 @foreach(array_merge($covidrecord,$dataCovid) as $data)

            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="d-flex px-2 py-1">
                  
                  <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                    {{--  <label>{{ $data->fullname }}</label>  --}}

                    <h6 class="mb-0 text-sm">{{$data->fullname}}</h6>
                    <p class="text-xs text-secondary mb-0">{{$data->gender }} ,{{$data->age }} वर्ष</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>

                <p class="text-xs font-weight-bold mb-0">{{ $address->province }}</p>
                <p class="text-xs text-secondary mb-0">{{ $address->district }}, {{$address->localgovernment }}<br/> {{ $data->tole }}</p>


            </td>    
            @endforeach
```

As I am using array_merge, it is throwing the error
//array_merge(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, object given

Comment: What actually is your problem here? Your main question is `How to pass 2 variable in 1 blade in laravel`, but upon reading the details you are able to pass 3 variables. I think your concern here is there's an error in `array_merge` function

Comment: Sorry , I wrote wrong title. My question is how do i use 2 variables in laravel blade. One variable is used for searching purpose and another variable is used to display name based on id from DB

Answer (score 1):

You can pass variables in a `compact` function:

```
return view('admin.dashboard.display', compact('data', 'dataCovid'));
```

Also please see [compact function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php)

Answer (score 0):

return like this

```
    return view('website.condo_living.index')->with([
        'var1'=>$var1,
        'var2'=>$var2,
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

to use 2 variables in foreach in your blade. It´s better that you pass you data from controller

```
return view('yourSubFolderView.View')->with('yourVariable')->with('yourVariable')
```

Also you can use

```
return view('yourSubFolderView.View')->compact('yourVariable', 'yourVariable')
```

**UPDATE**

in this line:

```
return view('admin.dashboard.display', compact('dataCovid'))->with($data);
```

change to:

```
return view('admin.dashboard.display', compact('dataCovid'))->with('data',$data);
```

and in your blade, you can access to $data or $dataCovid with for-each

in your code was missing your variable name `'data', $data`

Comment: I need code for foreach. Not for passing 2 variables.

Comment: @ShameeBajracharya you can´t use two variables in your for each. If you need to do this strictly, you should to do two for each one with covidrecord and other with dataCovid.
Also i have to say that array_merge in your blade it´s not better practise. Send your data modified from your controller. And if you need to do array_merge, you need two foreach

Comment: https://ibb.co/9WwXXnm

Answer (score 0):

FYI, the a covidrecord variable returns collections of data and a dataCovid variable that returns an array of data that you have to standardize the types of variables to deal with in the view array only or collection only

> I convert the data type to collection of array

and passing collection correctly from your method:

```php
public function recorddisplay(Request $request)
 {

    $search = $request->get('search') ?? "";
    if($search != "") {
        $covidrecord = DB::table('covidrecord')->where('fullname','LIKE',"%$search%")
               ->orWhere('province','LIKE',"%$search%")
               ->orWhere('district','LIKE',"%$search%")
               ->orWhere('localgovernment','LIKE',"%$search%")
               ->paginate(15)
               ->items();
    } else {
        $covidrecord= DB::table('covidrecord')->paginate(15)->items();
    }

     $dataCovid = DB::table('coviddeathrecord')
     ->join('district','coviddeathrecord.district','=','district.id')
     ->join('province','coviddeathrecord.province','=','province.id')
     ->join('localgovernment','coviddeathrecord.localgovernment','=','localgovernment.id')
     ->get(['coviddeathrecord.*','district.district','province.province','localgovernment.localgovernment']);

    $items = collect($users)->concat($data);

    return view('admin.dashboard.display', compact('items'));

}
```

and within the blade you can looping normal with collection of array like:

```php
     @foreach($items as $data)
    
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="d-flex px-2 py-1">
                      
                      <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                        {{--  <label>{{ $data['fullname'] }}</label>  --}}
    
                        <h6 class="mb-0 text-sm">{{$data['fullname']}}</h6>
                        <p class="text-xs text-secondary mb-0">{{$data['gender'] }} ,{{$data['age'] }} वर्ष</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td>
    
                    <p class="text-xs font-weight-bold mb-0">{{ $address->province }}</p>
                    <p class="text-xs text-secondary mb-0">{{ $address->district }}, {{$address->localgovernment }}<br/> {{ $data['tole'] }}</p>
    
    
                </td>    
                @endforeach
```

Comment: Do you mean  $items = collect($covidrecord)->concat($dataCovid);

Comment: yes take care with i replace Covidrecord model to DB statement and add items after paginate to get items only with an array type